# How to make octave figure windows float by default in i3 (window manager)

Tags: makefile, octave

I am automating the creation of plots from octave (with a makefile). But when the octave scripts are executed in the makefile, the octave figures are opened as tiled windows in i3. The problem is that when you save these figures (e.g. with `print -dpdflatexstandalone file.tex`) they are cropped to the tiled window size, which depends on your current layout.

I have already tried setting the figure size in the print command (`-Sxize,ysize`) but it only sets the plot size and the figure is still cropped to the window size.

Is there any way to make sure the plots are saved in a predefined layout independent of the figure window size?

I am curious about your ideas :D

Comment: I doubt that this is an issue with MATLAB as the graphics toolkits are completely different.

Comment: If you run Octave from a Makefile you typically want to use invisible figures. This can be done using gnuplot as toolkit or an OpenGL toolkit with OSMesa (if your GPU driver is MESA based) or using Xvfb.

Comment: @Suever: you're right. I removed the matlab tags

Comment: @Andy: I hadn't considered invisible figures (partly because the script is also used to display data, which of course needs visible figures, but of course I could insert a flag for the makefile...). And consequently I hadn't considered using gnuplot as graphics engine....

Comment: @Andy: You may consider posting it as an answer, as it solves the issue with arising when using i3. :)

Comment: Also I discovered I can make figures floating by default in i3 by matching the window title:
`for_window [title="Figure*"] floating enable` (in .i3/cofig)
Do you think it is worth posting as answer?

Comment: @Fabio I would have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments on the question I believe there are two possible ways to solve the problem:

1. make figures **invisible** (thanks @Andy):
   **Pros:** *faster* (doesn't have to open and render all figures)
   **Cons:** *limits use of script* (script cannot be used for visualization)
2. make octave figures **floating by default in i3** (`for_window [title="Figure*"] floating enable` in .i3/config):
   **Pros:** all *figures are opened*
   **Cons:** *could be limiting* (forces all figures in i3 to float)

I finally chose the second solution (for my particular problem) because I prefer all octave figures to be floating by default.
Were I ever writing a dedicated plot printing script, I would also make the figures invisible, while profiting from other figures to show and float.

Comment: fun fact: works with matlab as well! (as it uses the same figure naming by default)